# Single Linked List - Improvements - 1 - not complete

Tags: c++, c

TO DO

- exception handling
- merge with dynamic arrary

*SO Bug here--remove this line and Control K will not work

```
/* 
Added in comments from Jerry, Ed and Loki 
This code borrows from from http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/    
C++ Version - lnode, lnode_reverse, lnode_push, lnode_print, lnode_count 
*/
#include "c_arclib.cpp"
template <class T1> class sl_list
  {
  private:
    class node_1 
      {
      public:     
        T1 data; 
        node_1 *next;
        node_1(T1 data, node_1 *next = NULL) : data(data), next(next) {}        
      };
    node_1 *head;
    int count;
  public:
    sl_list() : count(0), head(NULL){}
    void push(int data) 
      {
      node_1 *newNode = new node_1(data, head); 
      ++count; 
      head = newNode;
      }
    void print() 
      {
      node_1 *current=head;
      while (current != NULL) 
        {
        cout << current->data << endl;
        current = current->next;
        }
      }
    void reverse()
      {
      node_1 *previous, *current, *future;
      previous=NULL;
      current=head;
      future=head;
      while(current!=NULL)
        {
        future=current->next;
        current->next=previous;
        previous=current;
        current=future;
        }
      head=previous;
      }
    void break_heap()
      {
      int i=0;
      while(1)
        {
        i++;
        push(1);
        }
      }
    };
/*
C Version - lnode, lnode_reverse, lnode_push, lnode_print, lnode_count
*/

typedef struct node_type 
  { 
  int data; 
  struct node_type* next; 
  } lnode_type;

struct lnode 
  {
  int data;
  struct lnode* next;
  };
void lnode_reverse(struct lnode*& head)
  {
  struct lnode *previous, *current, *future;
  previous=NULL;
  current=head;
  future=head;
  while(current!=NULL)
    {
    future=current->next;
    current->next=previous;
    previous=current;
    current=future;
    }
  head=previous;
  }
void lnode_push(struct lnode*& head, int data) 
  {
  struct lnode* newNode = new lnode; 
  newNode->data = data;
  newNode->next = head;
  head = newNode; 
  }
void lnode_print(struct lnode* current) 
  {  
  while (current != NULL) 
    {
    cout << current->data;
    current = current->next;
    }
  }
int lnode_count(struct lnode* current) 
  {
  int count = 0;
  while (current != NULL) 
    {
    count++;
    current = current->next;
    }
  return count;
  } 
void break_heap()
  {
  struct lnode* head = NULL;
  int i=0;
  while(1)
    {
    i++;
    lnode_push(head,1);
    }
  }
int main()
  {
  sl_list<int> list1;
  list1.push(10);
  list1.push(20);
  list1.push(30);
  list1.push(40);
  list1.push(50);
  list1.push(60);

  list1.print();
  list1.reverse();
  list1.print();
  }
```

Comment: what's the `break_heap` method for? It sounds malicious and it's public too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/* C++ Version - lnode, lnode_reverse, lnode_push, lnode_print, lnode_count
   I need node_type turned into a templated class..How does one do this?
*/
typedef struct node_type 
  { 
  int data; 
  struct node_type* next; 
  } lnode_type;
```

Turning it into a template is pretty straightforward:

```
template <class T>
class node_type { 
   T data;
   node_type *next;
};
```

Note that the `typedef` isn't really necessary (or desirable) in C++. You normally just want to use `class whatever`, and then the body of the class definition. This makes `whatever` usable as a name by itself, just about like the typedef would in C.

There's one other thing we probably want to do though: the whole basic idea of a linked-list node is really just an implementation detail of the linked list, so we really want to make the node type a nested class inside of the linked-list class:

```
template <class T>
class sl_list {

    struct node {
        T data;
        node *next;
    } head;

public:
    // Other stuff here.
};
```

From there, we want to write the functions that work with the data type to use `T` instead of `int`. For example, instead of your `push(int)`, you might write something like this:

```
void push(T data) {
  ++count; // prefer pre-increment when you don't need the old value.
  node* newNode = new node; 
  newNode->data = data;
  newNode->next = head;
  head = newNode; 
}
```

We might prefer to add a ctor to the node class/struct, something like this:

```
node(T data, node *next = NULL) : data(data), next(next) {}
```

With that, `push` becomes something like this:

```
void push(T data) { 
    node *newNode = new node(data, head);
    ++count;
    head = newNode;
}
```

[Edit2: Note that, as recommended by @LokiAstari, I've also moved the `++count` to *after* allocating the new node. This way if the attempted allocation fails (and `new` throws an exception), `count` will *not* be incremented, so it retains the correct values. If and only if the allocation succeeds, it's incremented to reflect the new node having been added to the list. ]

[Edit: and `node` would look roughly like this:

```
    struct node {
        T data;
        node *next;

        node(T data, node *next = NULL) : data(data), next(next) {}            
    } head;
```

]

Comment: Thanks...everything made sense except these lines:  
We might prefer to add a ctor to the node class/struct, something like this:
node(T data, node *next = NULL) : data(data), next(next) {}

Comment: The one thing I would add is exception safety. No operation that modify the object should be performed until all exception dangerous code has completed. Thus in push(), the ++count should be moved after the call to new. If new throw the state of the object is left in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @LokiAstari: Good point. Done.